# Normal Linear Regression - GLM with Examples in R (Dunn, Smyth)

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model

I have started reading this text, and I'm really enjoying it. The only thing is, I'm a bit confused with their section on Inference for Linear Regression.

They mentioned that in order to do inference, we have to assume that the response are Gaussian, which contradicts with most answer that i found in this site.  (i. e. The errors are gaussian, rather than the response) The book can be found [here.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441901170)

Comment: The correct assumption would be that the conditional distributions $Y \mid X$ are gaussian (of constant variance), but even that assumption is more a better thought of as an ideal scenario rather than a hard assumption.

Comment: What text do you recommend? Preferably an applied text, with examples.

Comment: Those end up being basically the same, and you’ll know you’ve reached a pretty good understanding of regression when that’s obvious (though it should be confusing at first).

Comment: Would you point me to resources, that would help me understand that they're basically the same?

Comment: You’re sliding a bell curve up and down the regression line. Whether you sample from a particular bell curve or if you take the mean of that particular bell curve and then add some noise (the error term), you’re doing the same kind of sampling.